# How can I make JQuery parse information and evaluate everytime it clicks

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I made this coding myself recently but just simply doesn't seem to work. This code is supposed to get the value of the name I've submitted and using ajax, if the name equals, "James", the code is supposed to return "Hello James" and just "Hello" for other names inputted. The response when the input is not "James" sort of works, but it only works some of the time and I also hope to fix that.

Tried reviewing some of my codes

```html
<fieldset>
  <form style="padding:15px;">
    <label for=name>Enter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" style="margin: 15px;" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
  </form>
</fieldset>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var send = {
      name: "name"
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process2.jsp",
      data: send,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```jsp
<% if(request.getParameter("name").equals("James")) 
{
  <% out.println("Hello James"); %>
} else { %>
  <% out.println("Hello"); %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/R4TPi1S  Open your developer tools, go to the network tab, make your ajax happen, find the request in the listing, click it, and look at it's response code and look and the actual respose that the request gives back.  This is some basic debugging you can do to make sure that 1) your request is happening, 2) It is successful, and 3) What it returns (if anything)

Comment: This `name: "name"` should be like `"name": name` ,also change your `<input type="submit"..>` to `<input type="button"..>` .